# Ubuntu ImportError: Could not import settings (works on Mac)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv

I am dealing with a strange problem. I have a Django app with this structure:

```
README.md
venv/
projectname/
    manage.py
    proj/
        __init__.py
        settings/
            __init__.py
            default.py
            celery.py
            local.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    app/
        __init__.py
        models.py
```

I have created a virtual environment like this:

```
virtualenv venv
```

Then I do:

```
cd projectname
source ../venv/bin/activate
python manage.py syncdb --no-input
```

This works beautifully on my development MacBook. I try the same command:

```
cd projectname
source ../venv/bin/activate
python manage.py syncdb --no-input
```

And I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/my-project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'proj.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named local
(venv)ubuntu@app1:/usr/local/my-project/projectname$
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this problem. Any tips?

All Django commands work locally on my MacBook (syncdb, celery etc) but there seems to be some issue on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you copied the original virtualenv from mac to ubuntu or you created a fresh one?

Comment: I created a fresh one. I just found out on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS there is still Python 2.7.3, on my Mac I got 2.7.6. But I am not using any new features. My code is quite old school so there should be no problem on 2.7.3.

Comment: any chance you missed some library in the new env? try to `python settings/local.py` as the error message suggests

Comment: Any way to fix this so it works on Python 2.7.3 as well? I don't want to mess with Ubuntu's Python.

Comment: did you verify local.py doesn't import a non existing library?

Comment: @Guy Yes, only thing it does is it uses relative imports.

Comment: For example: from .default import *

Comment: obviously you are declaring somewhere your SETTINGS, have you checked in your .bashrc profile if there is anything exporting the SETTINGS_MODULE for django?
For instance in my django virtualenv I have the following export:
`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="mypath.myapp.dev"`

Comment: In a Python shell, inside the venv, type: `import proj.settings.local`. What is the error? Also, is the parent directory of `proj` on the `sys.path`?

Comment: @sk1p import proj.settings.local returns  No module named local. When I do print sys.path, I have noticed the parent directory is not there on my Ubuntu box. It is there on my MacBook though. Could that be the issue? How do I fix it? How is sys.path generated?

Comment: There are different ways — it kind of depends on how you did the setup on the MacBook. For example, you can drop a `.pth` file in the site-packages directory, or alter the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Or you can leave the `sys.path` like it is and symlink the `proj` directory into the site-packages dir

Comment: @sk1p Even after doing that I am getting the same error. Interesting that I can do import proj.settings.default and that works.... but not prom.settings.local

Comment: What is the content of your `local.py`? Also, are your permissions OK? If you create a new file, `foo.py`, that only contains the `from .default import *`, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

OS X's filesystem is case-insensitive by default, but Ubuntu's is not. Make sure that the filename under Ubuntu has the correct case.